# GLSurfaceView(SKMapSurfaceView) freezes after adding to many annotations

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, skmaps

im using Skobbler maps framework and I have trouble with rendering annotations on map. There is this SKMapSurfaceView class that extends GLSurfaceView and renders using render mode RENDER_WHEN_DIRTY. This class provides method addAnnotation() which adds annotation to the map. After decompiling their code i found this:

```
public void addAnnotation(final SKAnnotation var1, final SKAnimationSettings var2) {
    if(var1 != null) {
        SKLogging.writeLog("SKMapSurfaceView", " Add annotation using ID =  " + var1.getUniqueID(), 0);
        this.deleteAnnotation(var1.getUniqueID());
        if(var1.getAnnotationView() != null && var1.getAnnotationView().getView() != null) {
            SKLogging.writeLog("SKMapSurfaceView", "@addAnnotationFromView ", 0);
            final SKCoordinate var4;
            if((var4 = var1.getLocation()) != null) {
                final SKAnnotationView var5 = var1.getAnnotationView();
                if(this.getContext() instanceof Activity && var5 != null) {
                    ((Activity)this.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            View var1x;
                            if((var1x = var5.getView()) != null) {
                                if(var1x.getMeasuredWidth() == 0 || var1x.getMeasuredHeight() == 0) {
                                    LayoutParams var2x = new LayoutParams(-2, -2);
                                    var1x.setLayoutParams(var2x);
                                    var1x.measure(0, 0);
                                }

                                final int var6 = var1x.getMeasuredWidth();
                                final int var3 = var1x.getMeasuredHeight();
                                SKMapSurfaceView var10000 = SKMapSurfaceView.this;
                                final int var4x = SKMapSurfaceView.b(var6, var3);
                                final Bitmap var5x = SKMapSurfaceView.b(var1x);
                                SKMapSurfaceView.this.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        int var1x = (int)((float)(this.a / 2) + var1.getOffset().getX());
                                        int var2x = (int)((float)(this.a / 2) + var1.getOffset().getY());
                                        SKLogging.writeLog("SKMapSurfaceView", "@addAnnotationFromView properSize=" + this.a + " centerX=" + var1x + " centerY=" + var2x, 0);
                                        String var3 = var5.getReuseIdentifierWithId();
                                        Bitmap var4x = this.b;
                                        if(SKMapSurfaceView.this.o.get(var3) == null) {
                                            SKLogging.writeLog("SKMapSurfaceView", "Bitmap DOESN\'T EXIST " + this.a + " " + this.c + " " + this.d, 0);
                                            if(var3 != null) {
                                                SKMapSurfaceView.this.o.put(var3, this.b);
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            SKLogging.writeLog("SKMapSurfaceView", "Bitmap  EXISTS ", 0);
                                            var4x = (Bitmap)SKMapSurfaceView.this.o.get(var3);
                                        }

                                        SKMapSurfaceView var10000 = SKMapSurfaceView.this;
                                        Bitmap var5x = SKMapSurfaceView.b(var4x, this.a);
                                        if(SKMapSurfaceView.this.a.addgpsuserpoifromarray(var1.getUniqueID(), SKMapSurfaceView.a(var5x), var4.getLongitude(), var4.getLatitude(), 5, this.a, this.a, var1x, var2x, var1.getMininumZoomLevel(), 0, var2.getAnimationType().getValue(), var2.getAnimationEasingType().getValue(), var2.getDuration())) {
                                            SKMapSurfaceView.a(SKMapSurfaceView.this, var1);
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } else {
            SKLogging.writeLog("SKMapSurfaceView", "addAnnotationWithTextureId  ", 0);
            this.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    SKCoordinate var1;
                    if((var1 = this.a.getLocation()) != null) {
                        double[] var2;
                        if((var2 = this.c.a.gpstomercator(var1.getLongitude(), var1.getLatitude())) != null) {
                            this.c.a.addcustomiconext(this.a.getUniqueID(), var2[0], var2[1], this.a.getAnnotationType(), this.b.getAnimationType().getValue(), this.b.getAnimationEasingType().getValue(), this.b.getDuration());
                        }

                        SKMapSurfaceView.a(this.c, this.a);
                    } else {
                        SKLogging.writeLog("SKMapSurfaceView", "@addAnnotationWithTextureId - Please set provide a location for the annotation to be added ", 1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        this.requestRender();
    }

}
```

It creates 2 new runnables. First one is run on ui thread and I'm calling that method from ui thread so this should be done synchronously. Second runnable is queued using GLSurfaceView.queueEvent() and after that requestRender() is called.

My problem is, that if I have multiple annotations to be added in loop:

```
for (SKAnnotation annotation : myListOfAnnotations){
    skMapSurfaceView.addAnnotation(annotation);
}
```

If myListOfAnnotations has about 50 items (can be less on slower devices) the map freezes until all annotations are rendered.

What causes the freeze here? Is it to many events being queued in GL or requestRender being called to many times in a short period of time, or am I mising something here? And how can I prevent this from happening? Is there any way to get count of queued events? Or some way to stop rendering and render it after all annotations are added?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: We are looking into the possibility of introducing a "batch" add function - hopefully this will reduce the performance penalties.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Whene I add 160 item on map, device performance so slow

Comment: yea i did. but im not realy proud of it:D basicaly you have to check the number of all annotation inside after adding each one in some while(1) cycle.
'
int actual = 0, expected = 0;
for(Annotation a : listofAnnotations){
  mapView.addAnnotation(a);
  expected ++;
  while(expected > actual){
   actual = mapView.getAnnotationAmmount();
  //yes, really...
   }

}
'
and when you remove some, you always have to keep the number of expected annotations to match the ammount of actualy shown annotations

Comment: Thank you @DominikMalík. I will try . I want to try override addAnnotation.